# How to add product thumbnail on orders list on backend?

Tags: plugins, woocommerce-offtopic, filters, order

I added product thumbail on cart with this

```
function getCartItemThumbnail( $img, $cart_item ) {

    if ( isset( $cart_item['image'] ) ) {
        return '<img src="' . $cart_item['image'] . '" />';
    }
    return $img;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_thumbnail', 'getCartItemThumbnail', 11, 3 );
```

It's works fine.(attach 1)
After the purchase i can't find that image on orders list, how to added the same image into order list ?
i can't added the same image into orders list on backend. (attach 2)

Can anyone help me ?

Thanks
[image: Attach1]
[image: Attach2]

Comment: Welcome to the WordPress StackExchange! Unfortunately, questions exclusively regarding 3rd party plugins is [considered to be off-topic](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and better asked using their respective support methods. Please [take the tour](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit our [help center](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help) to learn more. A better place to ask this type of question may be [The Official WordPress Forums](https://wordpress.org/support/forums/) or the plugin specific support.

Comment: Some alternative options: The [WooCommerce Slack Community](https://woocommerce.com/community-slack/) is very helpful for support. The [WooCommerce plugin support forums](https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/woocommerce/) can also be very helpful. If you're looking to hire help we suggest checking out the [WooCommerce Customizations](https://woocommerce.com/customizations/) section. Good luck!